# Azure Key Vault Backup/Restore Across Subscriptions

Tags: azure, azure-sql-managed-instance

I have 2 Azure SQL Managed Instances, each on a separate subscription.  I am trying to see if I can take an Azure Key Vault Key used for TDE in one subscription and back it up to then restore to a Key Vault on another subscription.  I have done this backup/restore within the same subcription but I am not sure if it is possible to do a backup and restore across subscriptions of these keys.  Any assistance would be helpful.

Comment: Are you using MSFT managed TDE keys or self-managed keys?

Comment: Customer Managed or Service Managed.  Using Key Vault Key